# nginx captive portal radius authentication

Tags: linux, nginx, authentication, radius, freeradius

I have multiple Ruckus Access Point and I want to provide a custom captive portal for guest authentication.

The thing I want is to check if user currently has access - then switch him to the site he wants and if not - show captive portal.

Can I do this with ngnix and something like [Freeradius](https://freeradius.org/)?

Comment: What IDM or identity services already exist (if any)? LDAP (AD, 389-ds or OpenLDAP), Kerberos (AD or Krb5), CAS, Shibboleth?

Comment: There is none such service currently

Comment: It might be called `sshd`, `openssh-server` or similar.